# Referencing a Service Array by Item unique Id from template

Tags: angularjs

I have an array that is populated when my app loads with all the members in the current group,

In the group service

```
//big array of member objects including their information, used all over the app
members = [{
           id:1111,
           name:'bob',
           ...more info
          },
          ... more users]
```

I want to only pass up their identifier(not the whole user object) when referencing the user in something they created (say for example a post).

```
post={
        creator_id:'1111',
        content:'im sad'
     }
```

BUT I need to show their name next to the post in the template.  What is the angular way to go about this?  I am thinking a custom filter but I dont know much about the init times of the filters and if this will run into issues if the user loads up a page that has it referenced in the template.  Any Ideas?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention this but my view of the posts is already in a directive that takes in the list of posts and displays them, I need a way to retrieve the user object (for individual posts within the directive template) from the array in my service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a directive is the angular, create a post directive, eg: ng-post, and pass the user object to it, bind the template in the link phase.

create a template

`Name: {{user.name}} otherproperty: {{user.address}}`

create directive, and pass info as an isolate scope

  `.directive('myPost', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        userInfo: '=info'
      },
      templateUrl: 'yourtemplate.html'
    };
  });`

how to use

```
 < my-post info="your user object" >< /my-post >

```

Comment: I forgot to mention this but my view of the posts is already in a directive that takes in the list of posts and displays them, I need a way to retrieve the user object (for individual posts within the directive template) from the array in my service.

Comment: I marked it as answer, thanks for the help.  I came up with a way to do it on init and as the items load.  Although your answer is exactly what I went with it is still a quality approach.  :)

Comment: ok, we do this in the service, for example, getPartialxxx(), and use array.map() to return the desired items

Comment: the service to retrieve user, also expose some method to retrieve partial of them, the result from server may contain lots of data that we don't interest, you can do that in the data-service, or wrap the data-sevice to a business-logic service, and compose your view model there, that makes your data-service much cleaner